# Disable jQuery UI slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a slider that I am trying to disable based on a jQuery if/else statement.

```
if (("#ceremony").checked) {
  $( "#ceremony_amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#ceremony-range-min" ).slider( "value"         ).toFixed(2) );
}
else {
  $( "#ceremony_amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#ceremony-range-min" ).slider( "disable" ).toFixed(2) );
}
```

This will disable the slider with no issues but when I go to checked the checkbox with the id = "ceremony" it does not enable the slider again.

I am trying to figure out if i'm not calling my checked attribute properly or if its something in my if/else statement. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `$` in front of `("#ceremony")` in the `if` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$( "#ceremony_amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#ceremony-range-min" ).slider( "value").toFixed(2) );
```

To

```
$( "#ceremony_amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#ceremony-range-min").slider("enable").slider("option", "value" ).toFixed(2) );
```

Comment: What is the difference in the use of "enable"?

Comment: Well, you "disabled" it, thus you must re"enable" before you can use it again

Answer (score 0):

You need to use change event on checkbox

```
$('#ceremony').on('change', function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $("#ceremony_amount").val("$" + $("#ceremony-range-min").slider("value").toFixed(2));
    } else {
        $("#ceremony_amount").val("$" + $("#ceremony-range-min").slider("disable").toFixed(2));
    }
});
```